# Codename one: TextField to keep some space during input

Tags: codenameone

How can i make my textFields that the user input does not start exactly at the margin, like when one starts to type some input some space is left, and also some TextFields that have a HintIcon i want the icon to remain there when user is typing the input.... but let it not be captured when getting the text like `.getText()`.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is padding not margin. It increases the space within the component from it's edges. Simply increase that number to achieve additional spacing.